# unicode utf8 error while moving working code to separate module

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am a newbie python programmer. I am strugling with strange error - which pops out only when I move working code from main script file to separate module (file) as a function. The error is SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 58: invalid start byte.
If the function is in the main code there is no error and code works properly...

The code is about do some webscraping with the use of selenium and xpath

```
#main file:
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import funkcje as f
spolka = "https://mojeinwestycje.interia.pl/gie/prof/spolki/notowania?wlid=213"
wynik = f.listaTransakcji(spolka)

#module file with function definition (funkcje.py):
def listaTransakcji(spolka):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(spolka)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='rodo-popup-agree']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='typ' and @value='wsz']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @name='Submit' and @value='pokaż']").click()
    page = driver.page_source
    #end of selenium-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #Store the contents of the website under doc
    doc = lh.fromstring(page)
    #wyluskanie rekordów transakcji - xpath------------------------------------------------------
    tr_elements = doc.xpath('//table//tr[@bgcolor="#FFFFFF" or @bgcolor="#F7FAFF"]/td')
    rekord = numpy.array([])
    length = len(tr_elements)
    for i in range (0, length):
        if(tr_elements[i].text=='TRANSAKCJA') or (tr_elements[i].text=='WIDEŁKI STAT') or (tr_elements[i].text=='WIDEŁKI DYN'):
            new_rekord=[tr_elements[i-5].text, tr_elements[i-4].text, tr_elements[i-3].text, tr_elements[i-2].text, tr_elements[i-1].text, tr_elements[i].text]
            rekord=numpy.concatenate((rekord,new_rekord))

    ilosc = (len(rekord))//6
    tablica = numpy.array([])
    tablica = rekord.reshape(ilosc, 6)
    header = numpy.array(["godzina", "cena", "zmiana", "wolumen", "numer", "typ operacji"])
    header = header.reshape(1, 6)
    tablica = numpy.concatenate((header,tablica))
    return (tablica)
```

## offending line 10:

```
import funkcje as f
```

## offending line 34:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @name='Submit' and @value='pokaż']").click()
```

## expected result:

```
["11:17:40","0,4930","0,00",24300,76,"TRANSAKCJA"]
```

## actual result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vox/PycharmProjects/interia/scraper.py", line 10, in <module>
    import funkcje as f
  File "C:\Users\Vox\PycharmProjects\interia\funkcje.py", line 34
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 58: invalid start byte
```

Comment: try putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of the new file (replace utf-8 with whatever encoding is used for `pokaż`)

Comment: Thats really strange but it worked! Why its strange? because the main file have no such line at all "#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-". What is more, after one run, I have deleted the line and it still works. It somehow fixed the issue? Thanks a million

Comment: @Marat: post as answer with explanation?

Answer (score 0):

thanks Marat!

> try putting # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on top of the new file (replace
>   utf-8 with whatever encoding is used for pokaż

solved issue... no idea why it happened in the first place though. Like new file that is not a main file is not utf-8 by default?

Comment: please don't post comments as answers.  I'll delete this comment later, but here's an upvote for your OP.